# irb Selenium-webdriver errors with Watir-automated Chrome

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, watir

***Hi, first of all I'm not sure if any of the information here is sensitive but just to be sure, I've redacted some of the numbers (I think to do with my web connection settings) except the port, please let me know if these are needed!***

I've installed the Chromedriver for v 28-31 of Chrome on Windows (I think it's currently on stable channel v29) and on the first load:

```
>require "watir-webdriver"
=> true
browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
```

Unlike in the [Watir installation guide](https://leanpub.com/watirbook) I got "Starting" not "Started" Chromedriver,  (the port wasn't as in the guidebook either) and then on the next line:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: unknown error: unable to discover open pages
    (Driver info: chromedriver=2.3,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64)
```

and then a list of "from" `/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.35.1/lib/selenium/webdriver` `/remote` `/chrome` and `/common`

Trying to reenter the process with `require "watir-webdriver"` gave `false` after that, so I exitted irb and retried which came back `true`

Obviously I'm wary of what's going on here, and thought it best to ask why I'm now getting the following error when repeating `browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome` :

```
Starting ChromeDriver (v2.3) on port ****
[****:****:****/******:Error:textfield.h(173)] NOT IMPLEMENTED
[****:****:****/******:ERROR:platform_thread_win.cc(127)] NOT IMPLEMENTED
==> #<Watir::Browser:0x54aff50c url="about:blank" title="about:blank">
```

After that, the commands (`browser.goto` etc.) were just working as normal, but wanted to find out what's going on if anyone understands these error messages?

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded the new chrome webdriver and was able to resolve the same issue.

http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.4/

Comment: installed it but no effect

Comment: I grabbed the latest version, not 2.4 (2.12 for me) and it worked well.